# composer git clone --mirror failed

Tags: git, ssh, composer-php, clone

I have private repo on stash and access with ssh key. I configured hostname, port, ssh file (_rsa) on `.ssh/config file`. Later I execute `git clone ssh://git@stash..` command on terminal. It works. When I execute `composer update vendor/repo:dev-master` command on terminal, This command failed and gives following error:

> Repository not found
>   The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission
>   to access it.
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

Answer (score 4):

According to the original poster:

> I solved problem by changing url in composer.json. Solution is `git+ssh://git@stash`.